# Flexlm license queued even though there are free tokens

Tags: flexlm

We are using flexlm license. There is a strange/unwanted behavior I suspect is related to some configuration. When we have certain number of free tokens, say 5, and a user is asking for 6, he is queued which is perfectly fine. Then another user asks for 3 tokens some time later. This second user is also queued behind the first user, even though there are enough free licenses for him. We want this second user be able to get the 3 tokens he needs while the first user is still queued for 6. How can we ensure that behavior from flexlm license manager?